# MySQL (JDBC) - Leaderboard ranking based on column values

Tags: mysql, jdbc, system, ranking

**Objective:**

- Find a rank for a given user identified by the "viewedUserId"

**Ranking:**

- The higher the experience the better (lower) the rank.
- If two or more users have the same experience the better rank will go to whoever achieved that experience first. (*updated_at* column which stores currentTimeMillis (bigint/long))
- Ranks should never tie. (No user should be able to have the same rank as another)

**Question:**

- Is it possible to calculate the rank within the query so that we don't have to manually loop through and compare every stored user's results. (Ideally we'd like to return 1 result with a rank)

**Code:**

```
public static int getRank(Connection connection, int viewedUserId) throws SQLException {
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT user_id FROM scores ORDER BY experience DESC, updated_at ASC");
        int rank = 1;
        while(resultSet.next()) {
            int userId = resultSet.getInt("user_id");
            if(userId == viewedUserId)
                return rank;
            rank++;
        }
        throw new SQLException("Failed to find rank for user: " + viewedUserId);
    } finally {
        DatabaseUtils.close(statement, resultSet);
    }
}
```

**Concern:**

- The above code will work how I intend for it to, but performance is a major factor. Using the above code is not ideal because our 'scores' table will consist of hundreds of thousands of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this in a query.  The simplest way in MySQL is to use variables:

```
SELECT s.user_id, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rank
FROM scores s CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rn := 0) params
ORDER BY s.experience DESC, s.updated_at ASC;
```

Almost all other databases support the ANSI standard functions `row_number()` and `rank()` for this purpose.  Also, if you have largish data, and index on `scores(experience, updated_at, user_id)` is optimal for performance.

EDIT:

To get a specific users rank, it is easiest to use a query without variables:

```
select count(*)
from scores s cross join
     scores su
where su.user_id = $user_id and
      (s.experience > su.experience or
       s.experience = su.experience and s.updated_at <= su.updated_at)
```

Comment: Would I have to select from those results to get a specific users rank?

If I add the following to that query:
WHERE s.user_id = 9017

The rank is 1, which isn't correct.

Comment: @Wonderlus . . . That is actually a very different question, see the edited response.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13703/get-the-rank-of-a-user-in-a-score-table

There they have a table like this:

```
Id  Name    Score
1   Ida     100
2   Boo     58
3   Lala    88
4   Bash    102
5   Assem   99
```

and add a rank:

```
SELECT id, name, score, FIND_IN_SET( score, (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score
ORDER BY score DESC ) 
FROM scores )
) AS rank
FROM scores
```

which results in

```
id name  score rank
1  Ida   100   2
2  Boo    58   5
3  Lala   88   4
4  Bash  102   1
5  Assem  99   3
```

You can also add a WHERE clause to filter for a single user.

Comment: Thanks. I did look at that post but it seems it does not correctly account for ties.

Comment: well then you should add another statement to the ORDER BY clause to also order according to another column.